what is the equivalent of numpy accumulate ufunc in pytorch
In numpy, I can do the following:
>>> x = np.array([[False, True, False], [True, False, True]])
>>> z0 = np.logical_and.accumulate(x, axis=0)
>>> z1 = np.logical_and.accumulate(x, axis=1)

This returns the following:
>>> z0
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]])

>>> z1
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])

What is the equivalent of this ufunc operation in pytorch?

I don't think there is a pytorch function that applies a function in a rolling fashion like np.logical_and.accumulate. You can use torch.logical_and to get the total result along an axis, but it won't give you the rolling results

The logical and corresponds to a product in binary terms. You can use cumprod for that:
>>> x.cumprod(dim=0).bool()
tensor([[False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]])

>>> x.cumprod(dim=1).bool()
tensor([[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]])


Another way to solve your problem is using a minimum function: If you think of it, joining a series of boolean values with and is the same as finding their minimum: if any value is 0/False, the result will be 0/False, otherwise the result will be 1/True.
In your case, as you want to propagate/accumulate the result, you can use the cummin() function:
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[False, True, False], [True, False, True]])

print(x.cummin(dim=0).values)
# tensor([[False,  True, False],
#         [False, False, False]])
print(x.cummin(dim=1).values)
# tensor([[False, False, False],
#         [ True, False, False]])


The advantage over cumprod(): your result will again be boolean, no need for an explicit conversion (also, the calculation might be a bit cheaper/faster, but this I didn't check).
The disadvantage compared to cumprod(): you will additionally need to access the values attribute of the result, as Pytorch's cummin() (in contrast to e.g. the one of Pandas) returns the result as a named tuple (values, indices).


In the same way, you could replace or with (1) a maximum function rather than a minimum function or (2) with a sum function rather than a product function.
